# BSON encoding a C# double[][] results in a Dictionary<string,double[]> in python

Tags: c#, python, json.net, bson

I have searched for answers in old messages so I apologize if this is redundant.  I should also say that I am a python newbie.

I have a C# app that is using Newtonsoft's BSON encoder to encode a double[][] of XYZ coordinates (each point has three coordinates e.g. the 'x' coordinate of point '0' is array[0][0], the 'y' coordinate of point 2 is array[2][1]).  These coordinates are then sent over a network using ZeroMQ to a python client.  The BSON data is then decoded using the PyMongo BSON module (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver).

I am getting structured data over to python, but my double[][] in C# shows up in python as

{u'1': [3.227, 0.0, 0.0], u'0': [4.081, 0.0, 0.0], u'2': [2.845, 0.0, 0.0]}

... a dictionary of strings vs. double[].  So, the first index is being interpreted as a string.  I want:

array[0][2]

... but the data structure that shows up requires:

array[u'0'][2]

So, to summarize, I want a double[][] to arrive in python but a Dictionary is arriving instead.  What am I doing wrong?

I have decoded this same data using the BSON codec from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bson/0.3.2 with exactly the same results, so whatever is going on, it is at least consistent.

My C# code is this:

```
static public byte[] Encode<T>(object obj)
    {
        MemoryStream memstr = new MemoryStream();
        using (BsonWriter writer = new BsonWriter(memstr))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj,typeof(T));
        }

        var retval = memstr.ToArray();
        return retval;
    }
```

And I then call that as:

```
byte[] reply = Streamer.Encode<double[][]>(mCoords);
```

... where mCoords is a double[][].

This is the binary data that python sees coming over the wire:

'\x80\x00\x00\x00\x040\x00&\x00\x00\x00\x010\x00m\xe7\xfb\xa9\xf1R\x10@\x011\x00‌​\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x012\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04‌​1\x00&\x00\x00\x00\x010\x007\x89A`\xe5\xd0\t@\x011\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0‌​0\x00\x012\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x042\x00&\x00\x00\x00\x010\x00‌​\xc3\xf5(\\x8f\xc2\x06@\x011\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x012\x00\x00\x00\‌​x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Any ideas?  Do I need to set some flag to tell the encoder to not use a string dictionary?  I am trying to stream data quickly so I would like the data to appear in the fastest, least-interpreted form as possible, hence my desire to not have to convert ints to strings all the time.

thank you for any help!

-denny-

UPDATE:
Well, here's a workaround.  I take all the binary data I want to transfer, wrap it in a dictionary and send that over.  The dictionary only has one entry (dict["0"] = myData;).  Then I ship it over to python where I extract the value from the first (and only) key and pass that up the stack to the callers who are none the wiser for my little wrapping trick.  Works like a charm, but it strikes me as a bit weird.  If someone has a cleaner, more correct solution, I would love to hear it.

Comment: Edit that into your Question.  At the very least, it will make it easier to read.

Comment: @Tory - thanks.  First time posting here.